# Tailwind CSS styles not applied on deployed NextJs app on Vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

All tailwind styles are broken on the deployed version
Localhost
[image]
Deployed version
[image]

MY tailwind config :

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    require("tailwind-scrollbar"),
    require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide"),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the JIT mode. Not sure how you are adding classes to tags, but if its dynamic JIT doesn't work properly. I faced similar issue during my recent development.

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    require("tailwind-scrollbar"),
    require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide"),
  ],
};
```

Comment: I Tried disabling it but still the same